# EGit: Merging two branches into a new one

Tags: git, merge, branch, egit

I am facing a problem with EGit. I am very newbie with Git and I'm still missing some aspects of it.

**Context**:

I have 2 branches, master and test on a Git repository. On Eclipse, I import a Git project with those two branches

**Goal**:

I would like to create a third branch (called MergeTestMaster) where I merge master and test

**What I've done**:

I've successfully created a branch and did the merge. I just have a problem when commiting (and not pushing) the merge into my local repository I get this result:

[image]

I just would like to have a simple branch created (just like the grey one) but instead it is merging master with test in MergeTestMaster.

**Questions**:

*1)* Will it be different if I push my changes on the server ? I am still working on a local repository

*2)* Am I missing something with the way I'm using origin/ // remote repositories ?

I checked out my MergeTestMaster branch in order to do some local work on it and then be able to push my changes to the server

*3)* Am I completely lost ?

**Edit:**

I also have this message from EGit saying that I am ahead of 43 commits, is that normal after such an operation ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've successfully created a branch and did the merge.

Yes, that is what you see in the version history view: the two following branches have been merged:

- `master` (fb8dea0)
- `origin/test` (44617f4)

The merge commit (1fb44e8) is referenced by the local branch `MergeTestMaster`.

Once you push that branch, `origin/MergeTestMaster` will reference the same commit as `MergeTestMaster`.

Comment: Does this mean that the tree won't look like this once I've pushed the branch ? I just need to do a 'git push -u origin MergeTestMaster' and that will be just fine ?

Comment: @DylanAlvaro the tree will look unchanged after the push. The only difference is that `origin/MergeTestMaster` will move and reference the same commit as `MergeTestMaster` currently does.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I also have a warning from Eclipse telling me I am 43 commits ahead (see edited post). When I am pushing, it includes every single commit done on test branch (43 commits on it). Is it normal ?

Comment: What branch does Eclipse tell you that it is 43 commit ahead? If it is MergeTestMaster, that sounds normal, since it will push any intermediate commit you might have done before the merge (both the intermediate commits and the merge commits are local, and need to be pushed)

Comment: Yes it is `MergeTestMaster` branch telling me that it is 43 commits ahead. The thing is that those commits have already been pushed from `test` branch my somebody else like 2 month ago. I've imported a new Git project, did the merge and now I would like to push. No intermediate commits have been done between the import and the merge. I hope my point is clear

Comment: @DylanAlvaro that ca make sense considering `MergeTestMaster` represents the merge between `test` and `master`. In any case,  apush should not republish commits already pushed before.

Comment: Ok it seems to work this way. Thank you very much for your help !